# How do I alter jdk in my Gluon Mobile project?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, gradle, gluon-mobile

I have tried to set the jdk in my `grade.properties` file in my `.gradle` folder like so: `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

But jdk 8 is still used by the project

I am using Eclipse on Mac and I have also tried to set jdk 9 in Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, as default.

How can I alter the jdk version used by the Gluon project?

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.28'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.directions.Direction'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    println JavaVersion.current(); 
    if (JavaVersion.current() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9) {
        compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'
        androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    } else {
        compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'compass', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'magnetometer', 'position', 'settings', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = '/Users/hemma/Library/Android/sdk'
        packagingOptions{
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

My `gradle.properties` look like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Monaco;
}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;
}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgray\c0;\csgray\c100000;\csgenericrgb\c100000\c0\c0;
}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/
\f1\fs22 \cf2 \cb3 \CocoaLigature0 hemma/Library/Android/sdk\
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f2 \cf4 \cb1 \CocoaLigature1 org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
\f1 \cf2 \cb3 \CocoaLigature0 \
}
```

When running the project's `./gradlew run` command from terminal I get build failed with an exception `Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`. And it does not matter if I set `org.gradle.java.home` to `jdk 9` or `jdk 10`. I guess the `grade.properties` should not look like mine does?

---

Even when I removed jdk 8 in java build path settings in Eclipse. The java 8 jre system library is added to a newly created gluon vm project.

[image]

The `gradle.properties` file contains the following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf200
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Menlo-Regular;\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Monaco;
}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;
}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgray\c0;\csgray\c100000;\csgenericrgb\c100000\c0\c0;
}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/
\f1\fs22 \cf2 \cb3 \CocoaLigature0 hemma/Library/Android/sdk\
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f2 \cf4 \cb1 \CocoaLigature1 org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
\f1 \cf2 \cb3 \CocoaLigature0 \
}
```

The Gluon plugin is version 2.6.0.v20180424-0818    for Eclipse oxygen

Comment: What is your jfxmobile version, what is your target platform? Post your build.gradle?

Comment: 1.8 is printed out when running on any platform. On iOS I get a message saying Gluon VM requires java 9 or higher. On Android I get a Android Support Repository not installed (It is installed). I can run it on desktop. I am targeting iOS and Android

Comment: If I set `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` in my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, running `./gradlew run` gives me 1.10. Something must be wrong in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

`org.gradle.java.home` must point to a directory. Try :

`org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Comment: It did not help

Comment: *jdk 8 is still used by the project* : for building right ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit the eclipse.ini file where it pointed to jdk8 to jdk10 bin folder. That allowed me to run with jdk 10. However gluon vm project was crashing. It was due to it compiled com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0 in build.gradle. So I had to include jdk 10 check so that dependencies look like the following

```
dependencies {
    println JavaVersion.current();
    if (JavaVersion.current() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9 || JavaVersion.current() == JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10) {
        compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'
        androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    } else {
        compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    }
}
```